# ADB auto detect port for adb connect

Tags: android, adb

Everytime I want to connect my adb server to my device, I need to explicitly give the port.

```
adb connect localhost:<port>
```

On my case, the port is randomly defined so I have to find it on the interface.
I try to netstat my computer but the port does not appear, except if I adb connect, and just a moment after I adb disconnect. But then it disapear again.

An other thing I thought was to brut force all ports but it takes like an ethernity..

If you have a suggestion I would be glad to read and test it.
Thanks

Comment: If you do netstat on your computer the port can not appear because it is open on your Android device. So you would have to run netstat on Android to see which on is open. Usually you specify the port to listen on when executing `adb tcpip` so a random port is pretty unusual. You may want to use a port scanner like nmap for fast finding the port that is open on your phone. Limit the nmap query to the ports that are used by the phone (or is it truely a random port 1-65535?)

Comment: Check https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi-android-11+ if you are using android 11+

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The fact is I am using bluestacks.

Answer (score 0):

similar issue.

a nmap example could be like:

```
nmap localhost -p 37000-44000 -oG - | grep -P '\d+(?=\/open\/tcp)' --only-matching
```

for me the port range [37000,44000] works fine ~